# Submitting MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $com_emails=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['com_email']);
 //$E=mysql_query("SELECT users.user_id FROM users WHERE users.email = '".$com_emails."' LIMIT 1");
 $E=mysql_query("SELECT users.user_id FROM users WHERE users.email = 'go1@go1.com' LIMIT 1");
 $E_row = mysql_fetch_row($E);
 echo $E_row[0];
```

When I use the $com_emails the query does not seem to work. If I manually add the e-mail it works just fine. I've also tried doing "'$com_emails'" but nothing seems to working.

IS there a syntax issue I am missing that is obvious

Comment: please start using `mysqli_*` as `mysql_*` is depracted and will be removed

Comment: Have you checked value of `$_POST['com_email']`?

Comment: The POST value comes in fine. I did an echo check on that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing an errors relating to mysql extensions being deprecated?  I assume that you have established your db connection prior to the call to `mysql_real_escape_string` ? I'd suggest you try something like the following just to see what is going on:-

```
@error_reporting( E_ALL );
$com_emails=$_POST['com_email'];
$sql="SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '".$com_emails."' LIMIT 1";

echo $sql;
/* Uncomment below if th sql looks correct etc */
/*
$E=mysql_query( $sql );
$E_row = mysql_fetch_row($E);
echo $E_row[0];
*/
```

Comment: It is very important to note that the above snippet should not be used in a real situation as there is no ( NONE ) cleansing of submitted data prior to being used in the db call - thus exposing your app to sql injection. It is highly advisable to start using PDO or at the very least mysqli. If you have lots and lots of code it is a pain the proverbial to migrate to PDO etc but in the end essential...